# Type of Reinforcing Mesh for Concrete

Tags: concrete

I'm looking at getting a **lot** of concrete work done and am looking to educate myself past the minimal anecdotal information I posses to be better armed when talking to contractors.

- What kind of reinforcing mesh should I insist on - [sheets](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Grip-Rite-Common-3-5-ft-x-7-ft-Actual-3-5-ft-x-7-ft-Steel-Remesh-Sheet/1000194987?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-LumberAndBuildingMaterials-_-MasonryMetals-_-1000194987:Grip-Rite&CAWELAID=&kpid=1000194987&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=1642&k_clickID=1789f1ea-f5aa-4712-9a11-5c09ffc97c88&gclid=Cj0KEQjwmv7JBRDXkMWW4_Tf8ZoBEiQA11B2fsBJARbdNAQkqc6F_QLXzEgBK_esjl-1Cnyyx0eiA5EaAjT98P8HAQ) or [roll](https://www.farmandfleet.com/products/136649-mazel-and-co-concrete-reinforcement-mesh.html?feedsource=3&gclid=Cj0KEQjwmv7JBRDXkMWW4_Tf8ZoBEiQA11B2fkImIdID1AQXERxAOWCws53gDFc_knr5BFXBUfFoBKsaAsBs8P8HAQ)? I've heard that roll is hard to make sure it's in the middle of the concrete and that improperly placed mesh can lead to rust stains on the concrete. (links are examples, not what I expect to purchase)

For some context, this is primarily for a driveway and garage floor.

Comment: There is also glass fill this works well for some applications and rebar. Knowing the type of work and thickness would be helpfull. One example 4" driveway or pattio (I would use glass in the driveway but not in the pattio welded mesh there).

Comment: I'm not familiar with reinforcing sheets. Do you have a link?

Comment: Interesting, Ed. I'd have done the opposite since steel is probably more reliable in a high-load situation. Maybe provide some reasoning.

Comment: This is for a standard driveway - 4" thick, and apron - 6" thick, as well as a garage floor. I've heard of glass reinforced as well, so I'd be interested in that option as well.